# Align cards with dynamic height using bootstrap 3.3.6?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Using Boostrap 3.3.6, my problem is content of Card body is dynamic so height will not be constant. So cards are not arranged properly. As per above image I want Package 5 should be displayed under Package 1 and Package 8 should be moved next to Package 7.

Html is responsive. Works fine with smaller screen but facing issue when full screen.

Any help will be appreciated, checkout my below code

```css
.card {
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1); /* off-white */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 3rem;
  
}



.card span {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.card-footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.card-header{
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cart</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
   
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 1 </span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>

                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 2 </span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                   
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                                <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                    <span>Package 3 </span>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        
                                    </ul>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 4</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
       
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 5</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 6</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 7</span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 8</span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use flexbox here? Or upgrade to bootstrap 4, this uses flexbox for rows/columns and you shouldn't have problems there.

Comment: @cloned I know bootstrap 4 works for issue but I cannot upgrade to bootstrap 4 because it is an enhancement to existing site.

Comment: you can try adding this css will resolve the space issue but willl work as row. div:nth-child(4n + 1){
  clear:left;
}

Comment: You can fix body hieght and add `overflow: auto` to scroll if it has more content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a class `row-for-cards` and set the display to flex. This can be your starting point, it should now behave as you wish. 
What's left to do: Some bootstrap3 classes interfere a bit with flexbox, for example the text flowing right to the edge of the card. But it's totally possible to get the layout to what you want exactly, I just don't know it from the top of my head. I think you need to add some flex-basis values to the cols (the same values as for width). And set `flex-basis: 100%` on mobile displays to get full 100% span on mobile devices.

```css
.row-for-cards {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1); /* off-white */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 3rem;
  
}


.card span {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.card-footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.card-header{
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cart</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
   
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-for-cards">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 1 </span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>

                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 2 </span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                   
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                                <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                    <span>Package 3 </span>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        
                                    </ul>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 4</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
       
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 5</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 6</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 7</span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 8</span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think to overwrite the CSS with flexbox.
It's probably the quickest way to do this.

This code will do the most for you:

```
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

See this example https://jsfiddle.net/wm9s50of/ to see this code in work (also with some extra finetuning).

Comment: you are changing bootstrap default class property and this is not good idea it will affect in whole page . Add your own class and use this property

Answer (score 0):

> Here is updated version of your code, i have added only display:flex; on main row and height:100%; on card div..

```css
.row.for-card{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.card {
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1); /* off-white */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
      
    }
    .row.for-card .col-lg-3.col-md-4.col-sm-12 {
       padding-bottom: 20px;
     }


.card span {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.card-footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.card-header{
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cart</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
   
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row for-card">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 1 </span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>

                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 2 </span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                   
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                                <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                    <span>Package 3 </span>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                        <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                        
                                    </ul>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 4</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
       
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 5</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                        <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                            <span>Package 6</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 7</span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                            <div class="col-12 text-center card-header">
                                <span>Package 8</span>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Description: This is a product.</li>
                                    <li>Price: $1,200</li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block ">Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use padding for space between boxes